# Use custom modules in Sagemaker MXNet

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, mxnet

I’ve been trying to use Sagemaker to run my custom MXNet training job. In all the examples I’ve seen, the code sample looks like this

```
estimator = MXNet(‘train.py’, role=role, other_params)
estimator.fit(inputs)
```

What if my `train.py` relies on a custom module? Given a directory structure like so

```
.
├── awesome
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── lib.py
└── train.py
```

With my `train.py` file importing from `awesome/lib.py`, what’s the best way for me to deploy this job on Sagemaker without going through the hassle of creating a Docker container.

Note: all the code in the custom module is just regular mxnet code, organized across various files and helper methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameters `source_dir` to point to the code location, and a `requirements.txt` file to add dependencies. This will avoid to touch docker at all. You can see those parameters in the SDK documentation (["Use third party library"](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_mxnet.html#use-third-party-libraries)), they are available both for training and deployment. See here an mxnet deployment example with additional dependencies in a `requirements.txt`

https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-yolov3-detection-server/blob/master/mxnet_detection_serving.ipynb